# Playing audio from a containerized website- where would the source audio be located?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

I've been trying to conceptualise a website that allows users to play short audio samples (about 10 in total on the entire site).

I've become quite interested in containers but don't have a great deal of experience in using them (hence the reason i'm considering this idea- to learn more).

I want to containerize/dockerize the website and was just wondering what the normal practice would be in terms of where the audio is stored. 
The containers would be running on a virtual machine in the cloud. Would the audio files generally be within the container (i.e. built into the image and present within the containers filesystem when the containers is run) or stored on the VM/node the container runs on and then referenced by the container? What would be the most common practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That really depends on what you see fit for your use case. If you have small amount of rather small samples, that does not change as time passes (without image rebuild) it makes perfect sense to bake them into the image. On the other side, if you want to ie. manage uploads via your website, or even just upload/manage them outside of your container and have these changes persisted over container restarts, then you need to mount external storage as a volume and keep the files there.